# Strange printing of R code using visual studio code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, tidyverse

Using R within VSCode leads to strange printing of the R code. I see strange characters where there should be spaces (I think). For example here is the output of loading the tidyverse library:

```
> library("tidyverse")
-- ←[1mAttaching packages←[22m -------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.2 --
←[32mv←[39m ←[34mggplot2←[39m 3.4.0      ←[32mv←[39m ←[34mpurrr  ←[39m 1.0.0
←[32mv←[39m ←[34mtibble ←[39m 3.1.8      ←[32mv←[39m ←[34mdplyr  ←[39m 1.0.10
←[32mv←[39m ←[34mtidyr  ←[39m 1.2.1      ←[32mv←[39m ←[34mstringr←[39m 1.5.0
←[32mv←[39m ←[34mreadr  ←[39m 2.1.3      ←[32mv←[39m ←[34mforcats←[39m 0.5.2
-- ←[1mConflicts←[22m ----------------------------------------------------- tidyverse_conflicts() --
←[31mx←[39m ←[34mdplyr←[39m::←[32mfilter()←[39m masks ←[34mstats←[39m::filter()
←[31mx←[39m ←[34mdplyr←[39m::←[32mlag()←[39m    masks ←[34mstats←[39m::lag()
```

Here is my user settings json file:

```
{
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.2.2\\bin\\R.exe",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code Retina",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,  
    "r.lsp.path": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.2.2\\bin\\R.exe",
    "r.lsp.debug": true,
    "r.lsp.diagnostics": true    
}
```

Now here is my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.0.10    purrr_1.0.0     readr_2.1.3
    tidyr_1.2.1     tibble_3.1.8    ggplot2_3.4.0   tidyverse_1.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pillar_1.8.1        compiler_4.2.2      cellranger_1.1.0    dbplyr_2.2.1
     tools_4.2.2         timechange_0.1.1    lubridate_1.9.0     jsonlite_1.8.4
     googledrive_2.0.0
[10] lifecycle_1.0.3     gargle_1.2.1        gtable_0.3.1        pkgconfig_2.0.3
     rlang_1.0.6         reprex_2.0.2        DBI_1.1.3           cli_3.5.0
     haven_2.5.1
[19] xml2_1.3.3          withr_2.5.0         httr_1.4.4          generics_0.1.3
     vctrs_0.5.1         fs_1.5.2            hms_1.1.2           googlesheets4_1
.0.1 grid_4.2.2
[28] tidyselect_1.2.0    glue_1.6.2          R6_2.5.1            fansi_1.0.3
     readxl_1.4.1        tzdb_0.3.0          modelr_0.1.10       magrittr_2.0.3
     backports_1.4.1
[37] scales_1.2.1        ellipsis_0.3.2      rvest_1.0.3         assertthat_0.2.
1    colorspace_2.0-3    utf8_1.2.2          stringi_1.7.8       munsell_0.5.0
     broom_1.0.2
[46] crayon_1.5.2
```

Any ideas on how to fix would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: that are ANSI Escape/terminal codes, use a terminal that understands them or configure R to not use ANSI color codes

Comment: I've tried to change to the radian terminal instead, but have encountered an issue with doing that. Here if interested: https://github.com/randy3k/radian/issues/391 . Thanks.

Comment: why don't you try powershell

Comment: I've never used R within powershell inside VSCode. I'll have a look into trying to do that.